# Difference between printf in Windows and Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, printf

Actually other than the core C language, there is a C library. And if my understanding is right, functions like `printf` are part of C library. Now I have programmed in C in Turbo C in Windows as well as using gcc in Linux.

My question is: Are the code implementations of functions like `printf` the same in both Windows and Linux? Ultimately the `printf` function has to call a function in core OS (in both cases) that would display ASCII characters onto the screen? So since both the OS are different, will the implementation of code for `printf` be also different in both the cases?

Comment: Turbo C is older than the first C standard, so don't expect it to behave like other standard conforming implentations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the implementation (of `printf` and all functions in `<stdio.h>`) is different (on Linux and on Windows), but the behavior should be conforming to the specification in the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) or [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard.

Notice that `printf` does not show characters on the screen, but send them to the standard output (see [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)). Something else -e.g. the kernel [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) layer and your [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) on Linux- is displaying the characters on your screen (or elsewhere!).

On Linux and POSIX systems, `<stdio.h>` is ultimately using [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) to write data to a [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). It would be [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (for `printf`) and the list of system calls is available in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Be aware that `stdout` is usually buffered (notably for performance reasons; making a `write` syscall for every written byte would be too costly). See [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) & [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html). Try using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your Linux program to understand the actually used syscalls.

On Windows, there is some equivalent thing (except that the list of syscalls on Windows is less documented and is *very* different).

BTW, GNU/Linux is mostly [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). So read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) then study the source code: the [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) is often [glibc](https://sourceware.org/glibc/) (but could be [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), etc... so you can have *several* implementations of `printf` on Linux, but usually you have *one* `libc.so`, even if you could have several ones), the kernel source is available on [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/).

Comment: And some parts of the standard C library, like `snprintf()`, are implemented with more fidelity to the C (C99) standard on Linux than they are on Windows.

Comment: In the case of text files, one difference is that on windows '\n' is translated into '\r' + '\n', while on Linux no '\r' is added to the output. Linux has to add the '\r' when displaying text on a monitor or when outputting to a text device like an old style dot matrix printer.

Comment: It is important to understand that parts of the standard C library are based on UNIX, because C was originally designed on a UNIX system.  Standard C libraries on Windows are essentially an emulation layer.  For example, on Linux, a C file descriptor is also a Linux file descriptor, so if a process has multiple modules linked to different C libraries, they can share file descriptors.  On Windows, a C file descriptor is an index in a table local to the runtime library; if a process has multiple modules linked to different C libraries, file descriptors cannot be shared between them.